# jqgrid converts the date based on time zone. How to restrict that

Tags: jqgrid

I have a Jqgrid for which i bind the data from the database and I do not have any problem in loading that. However with the date field i see an issue if the application is opened in another timezone with respect to server.

If my date in the database is '2018-03-15', in some timezones if data is populated as '2018-03-14' with one day difference, which i see happening because for the user in different timezones.

Do we have any option in the Jqgrid to restrict that conversion. I want to show the date that is in the database to the end user.

Here is the colmodel of that field:

```
{name: 'OrderDate', index: 'OrderDate', formatter: 'date', formatoptions: {newformat: 'y/m/d'}}
```

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used - Guriddo jqGrid, free-jqGrid or jqGrid ver <= 4.7? Also it is good to know the source date format  i.e what is the srcformat (does the format contain hours minutes and etc)

Comment: @TonyTomov: I am using "Guriddo jqGrid JS - v5.2.1"  and source date format is 'y/m/d'.

Answer (score 0):

Since your source date format is 'y/m/d' you will need to set this in the formatoptions, since the default source (srcformat) is 'Y-m-d' (this is set in the language file)

```
{name: 'OrderDate', index: 'OrderDate', formatter: 'date', formatoptions: {srcformat: 'y/m/d', newformat: 'y/m/d'}}
```

Also in case your source data does not contain any information that holds information for time zone jqGrid does not touch the data. Moreover we have a option called  **userLocalTime** (see language file used) which by default is false.

I'm not sure, but your problemn in this case is maybe in the server code. Check to see if your server code does not contain any code regarding time zone settings.

The real test is to see the source data comming from the server in the console.

**EDIT:**
Your source date format is so named Microsoft Json date, which comes from microsoft [json date serializer](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm)

In this case jqGrid automatically detect this type of date and if this date contain a information for the timezone offset. Your date as set from you does not contain information for the timezone - so the jqGrid does not add the timezone offset - it always convert this string to 2016/3/20

Another possible reason is that a userLocalTime is set to true, but you do not set this property in formatoptions.

IMHO the problem is in your server code, which somehow add the offset to your source date. Check this

Comment: I tried adding the src format and i still see no change in the behavior. I tried to log the date inputted to the server code and the date returning from the code. Here are those two logs: 
filter date: OrderDate='2016/03/20'
Date fetched: 3/20/2016 12:00:00 AM. please let me know if that gives more information to get the solution for the issue. I see the server sending the correct date and i assume its converting when binded to grid

Comment: So this mean that your source date that come from the server does not have the format you tell us (y/m/d)- maybe it is in other format as you post in last comment.  In order to solve the problem, please post your response from the server - the data that comes to the grid.

Comment: This is the response i see when i search for the date 2016/03/20. 
Response: "OrderDate":"\/Date(1458446400000)\/"

Comment: @TonyTomov I am also facing same issue. I see no resolutions yet on this thread.